# Audio Tracks are not playing when phone is on vibrate/silent

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, html5-audio, spotify

I'm using [ngAudio](https://danielstern.github.io/ngAudio/#/) to control audio tracks (spotify 30 seconds previews) on an ionic app.  It all works swell in the browser.  However, in both ionic view and the actual demo app, the tracks will only stream when I have the phone vibrate toggle turned to not silent/ring mode.  If it's in vibrate mode, the user hears nothing.  I've dug all over and can't seem to solve this riddle.

Here's my service:

```
 .factory('PlayerService', function(ngAudio) {

    var _play = function(show) {
        if (typeof audioObject === "undefined") {

            audioObject = ngAudio.load(show.track1_preview);

            console.log(audioObject);

            audioObject.play();

            audioObject.playing = show.id;

            return audioObject;
        } else if (audioObject.paused) {
            audioObject = ngAudio.load(show.track1_preview);
            audioObject.play();

            audioObject.playing = show.id;

            return audioObject;

        } else {
            audioObject.stop();
            audioObject = ngAudio.load(show.track1_preview);
            audioObject.play();

            audioObject.playing = show.id;

            return audioObject;

        }


    }

    var _pause = function(show) {

        audioObject.stop();

        audioObject.playing = '';

    }

    return {
        play: _play,
        pause: _pause
    };
```

Here's the controller:

```
    $scope.playStream = function(show) {

        PlayerService.play(show);

        $scope.audioObject = audioObject; // this allow for styling the play/pause icons
    }

    $scope.pauseStream = function(show) {
        PlayerService.pause(show);
        $scope.audioObject = audioObject; // this allow for styling the play/pause icons

        //console.log($scope.audioObject);

    }

    $scope.togglePlayPause = function(show) {
        if (!$scope.audioObject || $scope.audioObject.paused) {
            $scope.playStream(show);
        } else if (show.track1_preview !== $scope.audioObject.id) {
            $scope.playStream(show);
        } else {
            $scope.pauseStream(show);
        }
    }
```

Obviously, it's a bit of a crap user experience if someone has to put the phone off vibrate to hear the tracks.

I'm wondering if this is related to asyncronous stuff and mobile.  I just don't know.  Giving up after 4 hours of messing with it.

Comment: Does the phone have isolated volume controls?  That is, does it have a separate volume control for ringtone, media, and notifications?

Comment: @Makoto I think it's just my app because all other ios apps work fine when the phone is vibrate/silent.

Comment: I found this plugin which fixes this issue. It's specifically made to allow audio to play while the app is in the background, but another use case is that it fixes it so that the volume is controlled by the media volume, not the volume of the ringtone.  https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/cordova-plugin-backgroundaudio  The author says this about our use case: "Having only this Use-Case, your app may get rejected in the App Store, because you are not using the background feature. You have to remove the audio array in the UIBackgroundModes section manually in the <ProjectName>-Info.plist file"